# Apollo resetStore doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

please help;
I've got an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.client')

```
class FeedProfileBottom extends Component {

_onLogoutPress = function() {
  this.props.client.resetStore();
  return this.props.logout();
}

render() {
  return (
    <Root>
      <LogOutButton onPress={this._onLogoutPress}>
        <LogOutText>
          Logout
        </LogOutText>
      </LogOutButton>
    </Root>
  );
 }
}

export default withApollo(connect(undefined, { logout })(FeedProfileBottom));
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly binding the components scope to your logout function?

Comment: @NickZuber thanks, that worked.

Comment: I added this as an answer to your question — if this is how you solved it would you mind marking it as correct for other people who have similar issues to discover the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to explicitly bind the scope of your component to your function.

```
class FeedProfileBottom extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this._onLogoutPress = this._onLogoutPress.bind(this);
  }
  // ...
```